# Convert PHP code to Javascript to read numbers into sentences

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, parameter-passing

I want to convert my PHP code to JavaScript. The code's purpose is for read numbers into sentence. The problem is the sentence won't showing into input text. Here is the code:

#### JavaScript

```
function pembilang(angka) {
    var bilangan =[
            '',
            'SATU',
            'DUA',
            'TIGA',
            'EMPAT',
            'LIMA',
            'ENAM',
            'TUJUH',
            'DELAPAN',
            'SEMBILAN',
            'SEPULUH',
            'SEBELAS'
    ];

    if (angka < 12) {
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(bilangan[angka]);
    } else if (angka < 20) {
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(bilangan[angka - 10] + ' BELAS');
    } else if (angka < 100) {
        hasil_bagi == (angka / 10);
        hasil_mod == angka % 10;
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(trim(sprintf('%s PULUH %s', bilangan[hasil_bagi], bilangan[hasil_mod])));
    } else if (angka < 200) {
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val('SERATUS %s', terbilang(angka - 100));
    } else if (angka < 1000) {
        hasil_bagi == (angka / 100);
        hasil_mod == angka % 100;
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(trim(sprintf('%s RATUS %s', $bilangan[hasil_bagi], terbilang(hasil_mod))));
    } else if (angka < 2000) {
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(trim(sprintf('SERIBU %s', terbilang(angka - 1000))));
    } else if (angka < 1000000) {
        hasil_bagi == (angka / 1000);
        hasil_mod == angka % 1000;
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(sprintf('%s RIBU %s', terbilang(hasil_bagi), terbilang(hasil_mod)));
    } else if (angka < 1000000000) {
        hasil_bagi == (angka / 1000000);
        hasil_mod == angka % 1000000;
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(trim(sprintf('%s JUTA %s', terbilang(hasil_bagi), terbilang(hasil_mod))));
    } else if (angka < 1000000000000) {
        hasil_bagi == (angka / 1000000000);
        hasil_mod == fmod(angka, 1000000000);
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(trim(sprintf('%s MILYAR %s', terbilang(hasil_bagi), terbilang(hasil_mod))));
    } else if (angka < 1000000000000000) {
        hasil_bagi == angka / 1000000000000;
        hasil_mod == fmod(angka, 1000000000000);
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(trim(sprintf('%s TRILIYUN %s', terbilang(hasil_bagi), terbilang(hasil_mod))));
    } else {
        alert('Too many digits.');
    }
}
```

Then this is where I input the numbers:

#### html

```
<input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" onChange="pembilang(this.value);" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan nilai angka..." name="NILAI_ANGKA_AKHIR" type="number" required>
```

And this is where the sentence must be displayed:

#### html

```
<input id="NILAI_HURUF" value="" class="form-control disabled" placeholder="Masukan no induk..." name="NILAI_HURUF" type="text" required>
```

Comment: Hey, why my post was always given a score of -1 automatically?

Comment: Help, i found new problem. 

If the number is bigger than 20 then the sentences won't displayed again. How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by myself.

I just give a variable like this into JavaScript function :

```
angka = angka;
```

The solution is implementing/add JavaScript module from phpjs.org/functions/sprintf. Then the code for displaying that sentences is like this:

#### JavaScript

```
function pembilang(angka) {
    var angka = angka;

    var bilangan =[
            '',
            'SATU',
            'DUA',
            'TIGA',
            'EMPAT',
            'LIMA',
            'ENAM',
            'TUJUH',
            'DELAPAN',
            'SEMBILAN',
            'SEPULUH',
            'SEBELAS'
    ];

    if (angka < 12) {
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(bilangan[angka]);
    } else if (angka < 20) {
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(bilangan[angka - 10] + ' BELAS');
    } else if (angka < 100) {
        hasil_bagi = Math.floor(angka / 10);
        hasil_mod = angka % 10;
        //   example 4: sprintf("%s", 123456789012345);
        var x = sprintf("%s PULUH %s", bilangan[hasil_bagi], bilangan[hasil_mod]);
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(x);
    } else if (angka < 101) {
        var x = sprintf("SERATUS %s", bilangan[angka - 100]);
        $('#NILAI_HURUF').val(x);
    }else {
        alert('Maksimal nilai 100.');
    }
}
```

Comment: (I've flagged this for quality issues - there is already another self-answer, and it is not clear what this answer is trying to convey).